# Qlikview difference in SR4 and SR2

Tags: qlikview

I wonder if anyone can help me or if they have seen the same issue.

I have Qlikview 11 SR4 installed on my computer and the web server is Qlikview 11 SR2.

If I load the exact same sheet with exact the same .qvds I get different totals in the charts even though it is exactly the same data. Is this an issue in SR4 or in SR2?

Comment: are you sure you do not have any hidden selections when you use web? AccessPoint will remember your sessions and it is possible to hide selections with if HidePrefix statement is used in a script. Also are you using any advanced calculations like AGGR?

Another idea, open your document in a desktop client, note the total and switch to a web mode - will it be the same?

Comment: One other point to check is if you are using the QlikView IE plug-in is to make sure it is the same version (e.g. SR4) as it is a separate install.